# How to show that a random variable $X$ whose distribution is infinitely divisible, then $X$ is either degenerate or unbounded?

Tags: probability, probability-theory

The question is:

Suppose $X$ is a random variable whose distribution is infinitely divisible. Show that $X$ is degenerate or unbounded?

$\textbf{My attempt}$: For each $n \geq 1$ $X_1,...,X_n$ are i.i.d random variable such that $\sum_{k=1}^n X_k$ has the same distribution as $X$.

Suppose that $X$ is a bounded random variable.

Let $C>0$ such that $P(|X|>C)=0$. Then for each $n \geq 1$,
\begin{equation*}
0=P(X>C)\geq P\left(X_1>\frac{C}{n},X_2>\frac{C}{n},...,X_n>\frac{C}{n}\right)= P^n(X_1> \frac{C}{n})
\end{equation*}
So, $P\left(X_1> \frac{C}{n}\right)=0$. Similarly, $P\left(X_1< -\frac{C}{n}\right)=0$.
So, $|X_1| \leq \frac{C}{n}$ a.s.

The question is how do I calculate the $Var(X_1)$ from this relation?

I understand that the $\text{Variance}$ in the one equality remains positive and on the other side it becomes zero. That makes the contradiction here.

Can anyone help me in the last few steps of my solutions?

Comment: Your $X_1, \ldots, X_n$ do not have the same distribution as $X$ but they are mutually independent and have a common distribution which is generally different from that of $X.$

Comment: I actually wrote an answer. I will delete my comments.

Comment: Also, there is no need for contradiction. You can show directly that $X$ is degenerated.

Comment: After you ask a question here, if you get an acceptable answer, you should "accept" the answer by clicking the check mark $\checkmark$ next to it. This scores points for you and for the person who answered your question. You can find out more about accepting answers here: [How do I accept an answer?](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/3286/), [Why should we accept answers?](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/3399/), [What should I do if someone answers my question?](https://math.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $X' = X_1 - X_2$ with $X_1$ and $X_2$ two independent copies of $X.$ Then $X'$ is a symmetric random variable, *a fortiori* $\mathbf{E}(X') = 0.$ If we show $X'$ is degenerated, then $X' = 0,$ which would imply that $X_1 = X_2,$ which further implies $X$ is independent of itself, *a fortiori* $X$ is also degenerated. This construction also shows that $X'$ is infinitely divisible where at each stage, the summands are also symmetric random variables.

The previous paragraph showed that sufficied to show the result under the stronger assumptions that $X$ is bounded, infinitely divisible, symmetric and for each $n \in \mathbf{N},$ $X = \sum\limits_{k = 1}^n X_{n, k}$ where the $(X_{n,k})$ are symmetric, independent with a common distribution $F_n.$ Following what you did, one see that,
$$
|X_{n,1}| \leq \dfrac{c}{n}.
$$
By symmetry, $\mathbf{V}(X_{n,1}) = \mathbf{E}(X_{n,1}^2) \leq \frac{c^2}{n^2}.$ Since $\mathbf{V}(X) = n \mathbf{V}(X_{n,1}),$ we see at once that $\mathbf{V}(X) = 0$ and $X = 0$ a.s. Q.E.D.